# Page.Header.Controls.Add(control) is adding controls to <body> not <head>

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I'm trying add some code at run time to the head element.  When I do this in the page load of a user control in the page:

```
HtmlGenericControl hc = new HtmlGenericControl();
hc.InnerHtml = GetParameter("HeaderCode");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(hc);
```

The control ends up in the body tag, as the first child element.  For Example:

```
...
</head>
<body>
<span><meta>Test</meta></span>
...
```

From my understanding, the Page.Header is supposed to be the Head element.  In the aspx page, the head has the `runat="server"` attribute set.

Any idea how I can inject a string in to the `<head>` element?

Comment: In the case of the example, GetParameter is returning a string of value: "<meta>Test</meta>"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The head element may have restrictions on the type of content. When we inject javascript into the header, we do it using a LiteralControl.

For example:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('test');</script>"))
```

Comment: This was the issue.  When adding a  HtmlGenericControl it wraps it with a span tag.  Chrome and IE move the span tag to the body, you can see if you view the page source and inspect the element.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to add javascript, css or any other resources such as meta tags. I have successfully implemented this code on my website :

```
HtmlGenericControl my_js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            my_js.Attributes["async"] = "async";
            my_js.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
            my_js.Attributes["src"] = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
            Page.Header.Controls.Add(my_js);
```

You need to use namespace : "using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" to use HtmlGenericControl.