# Cannot get inner content of head because the contents are not literal. - Trying to append to Header

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, header

I have an aspx page with a head

```
<head runat="server" id="head">
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Now the site I am working on is pulling information from a xml file and I want to take a node from the xml file and append it to the head section.

```
 <head runat="server" id="head">
        <title></title>
        <script></script> // comes from the xml file
    </head>
```

However when I try to either one of these.

```
  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        this.Page.Header.InnerHtml += xml.Header; // errors out
        this.Page.Header.InnerHtml = this.Page.Header.InnerHtml + xml.Header; // errot ut

    }
```

It errors out

> System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code   Message=Cannot
>   get inner content of head because the contents are not literal.

If I do this

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.Page.Header.InnerHtml = xml.Header; 


        }
```

all is fine.

If I do this

```
<head runat="server" id="head">
   // removed the title tag so now nothing is in head
</head>
```

and then do this

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.Page.Header.InnerHtml += xml.Header; // works
            this.Page.Header.InnerHtml = this.Page.Header.InnerHtml + xml.Header; //works

        }
```

It works. So I am not sure why it fails when there is tags inside the head already.

If I also try to get the contents from the head as well I get the same error

```
 var a = this.Page.Header.InnerHtml;
var a = this.Page.Header.InnerText;
```

Comment: What content are you wanting to get from the head tags.. have you tried using script tags to get the information that you are needing I am not sure what you are trying to get from the <head> tag

Comment: I want to get everything in the head. Whatever is in it title,links,content place holder, scripts. So it is not something I really want to parse through it should be a dump

Comment: If all you're trying to do is append to header, then you're going about it the wrong way. You're concatenating like it's a string when I think you should work with it like the XML that it is!

Comment: This is what I mean.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537571/page-header-controls-addcontrol-is-adding-controls-to-body-not-head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue might be due to the way the head tag is getting rendered with the script tag in it

It can also be that the page is getting render too quickly

I would suggest that you try insert the script tag in the head tag while page is getting Page_PreRender event

Comment: Well script was just an example. The xml file can have anything in it(well anything for a valid header). It could have scripts, links whatever. I can try Page_PreRender and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with (VB):

```
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim w As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    NameOfYourElementID.RenderControl(w)
    Dim s As String = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString()
```

Now you can use variable 's' to do any work on it.

Don't forget to import System.IO to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when using MasterPage. this.Page.Header.InnerHtml not work